# Benchmark an SSD

Tags: ssd

What is the best way to test/benchmark an SSD to make sure it's doing it's job.  I invested in an SSD, have my OS on it, want to make sure I am getting my money's worth.

I have heard some people making claims along the lines of:
"I've had my SSD for X months and my read/write speeds have dropped Y%'.

What is the best way to test for things like that (and what are good numbers to look for)?

For reference I have a Samsung 830 128gb.

Answer (score 0):

There are all sorts of benchmarking programs for SSDs. I would recommend [AS SSD](http://alex-is.de/PHP/fusion/downloads.php?download_id=9). SSD technology has gotten better over the last few years, so you shouldn't experience slowdowns for several years, certainly not in a period of months. You can benchmark every so often to see, but that is itself creating wear. Anyway, the Samsung 830 series is a good one, so you should be good to go for a while.